# Processing variables inside string from file

Tags: arrays, bash, eval

So I'm attempting to grab some syslogs from a file like this one.

```
$date  INT-FW01 : %ASA-6-106100: access-list inside denied udp inside/172.29.2.101(1039) -> outside/192.203.230.10(53) hit-cnt 1 first hit [0xd820e56a, 0x0]
```

I will be replacing the time-stamp and IP addresses of the individual logs which are taken from the file and stored inside an array. 
here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
file=log_store
gen_ip() {
        echo $((RANDOM%256)).$((RANDOM%256)).$((RANDOM%256)).$((RANDOM%256))
}
timestamp() {
        date +"%b %d %H:%M:%S"
}
ip=$(gen_ip)
date=$(timestamp)
if [ -e $file ];  then
        readarray -t logs < $file
else
        echo "$file is not present"
fi

cmd='cmd=${logs[0]}'
eval $cmd
echo $cmd
```

this code seems to echo the first array item but it isn't replacing the $date from the file, it simply prints "$date".
From my tests the eval seems to work on other arrays I've defined inside the program except for the log array so i'm a little stuck!

Comment: I don't see any replacement logic within your code

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I was hoping that the eval would process the variables. for example, when you create a string that contains a variable, the eval command will replace them with the variable contents. so when foo='$bar' is run through eval $foo then echo $foo it should print whatever $bar was

Comment: *replacing the time-stamp and IP addresses of the individual logs* - and how IP address is replaced?

Comment: @RomanPekherest i would write $ip in the text file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
cmd='cmd=${logs[0]}'
```

to:

```
cmd="cmd=\"${logs[0]}\""
```

Your single quotes are preventing the expansion of the `${logs[0]}` variable, so `$cmd` contains that literally. Then `eval` expands that variable, which results in `$date`. You need the first expansion so that the value of the variable becomes

```
cmd='$date  INT-FW01 : %ASA-6-106100: access-list inside denied udp inside/172.29.2.101(1039) -> outside/192.203.230.10(53) hit-cnt 1 first hit [0xd820e56a, 0x0]'
```

and then `eval` will expand the `$date` variable.

You need the double quotes around `${logs[0]}` so that it won't try to parse the rest of the line as a shell command, but will still expand variables in it. And they have to be escaped so they can be put inside the `cmd` string.

You should also quote the variable when you use `eval` and `echo`:

```
eval "$cmd"
echo "$cmd"
```

to prevent additional word splitting and globbing of the result.

Comment: It's interesting because this seems to work perfectly fine;                 'logs=( "this is a $date" )
packet='packet=${logs[0]}'
eval $packet
echo $packet'
it seems not to like single quotes on the array i've found.                               I also returned an error with removing the quotes.

Comment: Variables are expanded in double quotes, not in single quotes.

Comment: So when you write `logs=("this is a $date")` it expands the variable there.

Comment: See [difference between single and double quotes in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

Comment: aaah ok I see what you mean so i'd need to write cmd="${logs[0]}" which should return the log and then push that through eval?

Comment: @barmer so i'm now getting this error ./program.sh: eval: line 19: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: What's on line 19?

Comment: this is what's there: eval $cmd

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. What does `echo "$cmd"` show before the `eval`?

Comment: The best way to debug a shell script is to put `set -x` at the beginning. Then you'll see all the variable expansions as it's executing. This should help you.

Comment: so this is my code in it's current state #!/bin/bash
file=log_store
gen_ip() {
        echo $((RANDOM%256)).$((RANDOM%256)).$((RANDOM%256)).$((RANDOM%256))
}
timestamp() {
        date +"%b %d %H:%M:%S"
}
ip=$(gen_ip)
if [ -e $file ];  then
        readarray logs < $file
else
        echo "$file is not present"
fi
date=$(timestamp)
packet="${logs[0]}"
echo $packet
eval $packet
echo $packet

Comment: and this is the error: $date INT-FW01 : %ASA-6-106100: access-list inside denied udp inside/172.29.2.101(1039) -> outside/192.203.230.10(53) hit-cnt 1 first hit [0xd820e56a, 0x0]
./picnmix.sh: eval: line 18: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./picnmix.sh: eval: line 18: `$date INT-FW01 : %ASA-6-106100: access-list inside denied udp inside/172.29.2.101(1039) -> outside/192.203.230.10(53) hit-cnt 1 first hit [0xd820e56a, 0x0]'
$date INT-FW01 : %ASA-6-106100: access-list inside denied udp inside/172.29.2.101(1039) -> outside/192.203.230.10(53) hit-cnt 1 first hit [0xd820e56a, 0x0]

Comment: It's putting the entire line in `logs[0]` instead of just the first field.

Comment: is there not a way to process the whole line and the variables in it?

Comment: See the updated answer. You need single quotes around `${logs[0]}` inside the double quotes.

Comment: so i've updated to match the answer                                       date=$(timestamp)
packet="packet='${logs[0]}'"
eval "$packet"
echo "$packet"
the output of this is now: $date INT-FW01 : %ASA-6-106100: access-list inside denied udp inside/172.29.2.101(1039) -> outside/192.203.230.10(53) hit-cnt 1 first hit [0xd820e56a, 0x0]
i'm so confused and sorry about this haha

Comment: Ugh, I also made a single vs. double quote error. They need to be escaped double quotes around `${log[0]}`